# Ramanujan’s identity $A^A+B^B+C^C$= $P^P+Q^Q+R^R$.

Tags: number-theory

[image]

Recently I had visited S. Ramanujan’s house in Kumbakonam which has now been converted to a museum. There , came across the above given display card having identities involving integers having the same exponents as the digits themselves. Is there a concrete method to arrive at such identities or is it just by brute force that one arrives at them?

Comment: Remember that Ramanujan was a genius. That being said, I would be surprised if there was some method for coming up with these.

Comment: The difficult part is coming up with $A^AB^BC^C\cdots = P^PQ^QR^R\cdots$.  You can then make $A+B+C+\cdots=P+Q+R+\cdots$ by having enough $1$s on one side or the other.  You can also have duplicates on both sides.  So the first two essentially start with $2^2 6^6 = 3^3 3^3 4^4$  which is really saying that $6^6$ is  $(3^3)^2$ multiplied by a power of $2$.  He could equally have said $1^11^11^11^11^11^16^6  = 2^22^22^2 3^33^3$ and $1+1+1+1+1+1+6=2+2+2+3+3$.  The smallest case may be $1^11^11^11^14^4=2^22^22^22^2$ and $1+1+1+1+4=2+2+2+2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p_n$ be the sequence of all primes (preferably in ascending order). Every integer $k$ can uniquely expressed as a product $k = p_1^{k_1} \cdot p_2^{k_2} \cdot \ldots$, where the $k_i$ are nonnegative integers ($k_i$ is the $p_i$-adic valuation of $k$), and most of the $k_i$ are zero. Let's call $(k_i)$ the valuation sequence of $k$.

Now note that if $c = a \cdot b$, then $c_i = a_i + b_i$ for all $i$. So products of integers correspond to sums of their valuation sequences.

Now let's list the valuation sequences of numbers of the form $n^n$:

$1^1$ corresponds to $(0, 0, 0, \ldots)$,

$2^2$ corresponds to $(2, 0, 0, \ldots)$,

$3^3$ corresponds to $(0, 3, 0, \ldots)$,

$4^4$ corresponds to $(8, 0, 0, \ldots)$,

$5^5$ corresponds to $(0, 0, 5, \ldots)$,

$6^6$ corresponds to $(6, 6, 0, \ldots)$,

and so on. Now finding a product identity is simply a matter of finding matching integer linear combinations of the valuation sequences. There's bound to be a lot of them, since the dimension of the vector space spanned by the valuation sequences of $1^1, \ldots, n^n$ is equal to the number of primes between $1$ and $n$, and that's a lot less than $n$.

The first identity can be found like this:

$$(0, 0, 0, \ldots) + (0, 0, 0, \ldots) + (2, 0, 0, \ldots) + (6, 6, 0, \ldots) = (0, 3, 0, \ldots) + (0, 3, 0, \ldots) + (8, 0, 0, \ldots),$$

therefore

$$ 1^1 \cdot 1^1 \cdot 2^2 \cdot 6^6 = 3^3 \cdot 3^3 \cdot 4^4.$$